# What am I doing wrong? (C++ strings)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    string a;
    cin >> a;

    int index;

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=="?")
        {
            index=i;
        }
    }

    cout << index;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to find the "?" in the string if there is any, but I get error:
"ISO C++ forbids comparasion between pointer and integer"

Any help?

Comment: Why are you using `<cstring>` functionality on a `std::string`?

Comment: will `strlen(a)` work as well?

Comment: You need to `#include <string>` instead of `<cstring>` and use `a.size()` or `a.length()` instead of `strlen(a)`.

Comment: Characters are delimited by ' while character-strings are delimited by ". So '?' Is the character `?` while "?" Is a string of length 1 (plus the null terminator) the contains the character `?` and '\0'.

Comment: "Any help?" comes across as a bit pointed. Would you consider rephrasing your question?

Answer (score 7):

Use single quotes around the '?' character to indicate a char instead of a string.  That's why your comparison is failing.

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to telling somebody with a gaping head-wound about how they really need to trim their fingernails.

Answer (score 5):

A: Mixing C++ strings and old C style (strlen) functions in your for loop (use `a.length()` instead)

B: Comparing C strings to chars `if(a[i]=="?")` should be `if(a[i]=='?')` (use single quotes to compare characters - double quotes makes it a string compare which is actually a pointer compare, and will not do what you expect)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, your program can be reduced to the following with the use of some handy built-in functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::getline(std::cin, a);

    int index;

    auto pos = a.find("?");

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
      index = pos;
   else
      index = -1;

    std::cout << index;
}
```

#### Advice:

- Use `<string>` instead of `<cstring>`,
- When working with input and strings, use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `std::cin` to consume the entire line,
- [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is a better alternative than looping manually.

Answer (score 2):

> any help?

1. you cannot call c function strlen() on instance of object
   std::string use std::string::length() instead
2. operator[] of std::string returns type char you are trying to compare with string constant which has type const char *
3. You use uninitialized variable index and if your condition never succeded (assuming you fix it eventially) you have no way to find that out
4. std::string has method find() that returns position in string or constant std::string::npos if it cannot find

Answer (score 1):

Comments inline...

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cstring> // You don't need this
#include <string> // You do need this

// using namespace std; // You don't need this

int main()
{
    // int n; // This is not used
    // cin >> n; // Nor is this

    std::string user_input; // Use std:: and meaningful variable names
    std::cin >> user_input; // "

    int index = user_input.find('?'); // This is the simplest way to find a character

    // for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) // strlen() does not work here
    // {
    //  if(a[i]=="?") // chars are quoted with single quotes, as above. This is {'a', '\0'}
        //{
            // index=i; You could break here, too, otherwise you'll reurn the last '?'
        //}
    // }

    std::cout << index;

    // return 0; // This is unnecessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"?"` creates a string in the memory. A constant string like `"?"` will point to the start of the address in the memory. Hence it is a pointer.

`'?'` creates a single character, in place, and no pointers are created. Hence, when comparing with another character or integer, ISO C++ forbids when you try to compare an integer(or a character) with a pointer(example a string).

So it should be

```
    if(a[i]=='?')
    {
        index=i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I shall demonstrate how to find a single* question mark ('?') from a std::string:
Make sure to read the comments!

```
int main( void )
{
    // DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
    // Declare strA as std::string
    std::string strA = "";
    // Declare nIndex as int. We set the value of it to -1 to let us know
    // if there were any '?' within strA
    int nIndex = -1;

    // INITIALIZE
    // Set the value of strA to the line that was inputted
    // You might want to loop this until the length of strA
    // is greater than 0
    std::getline( std::cin, strA );

    // SEARCH FOR THE FIRST '?'
    // if std::string::find returns -1, then no '?' was found within strA
    nIndex = strA.find( '?' );

    // CHECKING AND PRINTING nIndex
    // Remember why strA is -1?
    if( nIndex == -1 )
        std::cout << "The inputted string does not contain any '?'...\n";
    else std::cout << "The first '?' is found at: " << nIndex;

    // DONE

#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "\nDebugging > Paused! Enter any key to continue...\n";
    ::getchar( );
#endif // DEBUG
    return( 0 );
};
```